# Grails countrySelect tag - default value

Tags: grails

This is my code

```
<g:countrySelect name="country" value="${customerInstance?.country}"
             noSelection="['':'-Choose your country-']"/>
```

In show view(page)
    It displays the value, instead of that i want it to display the selected option

for example,
    
    -Choose your country-
    Afghanistan
    Albania
here in above example i want the show page to display option ("Afghanistan") instead of that value ("alg"), this is my question help me out of this problem

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You want to get this value on the client side or server side? What are you doing to try to edit the selected country?

Comment: i want to get this value on the server side, for example in a grails application i have a field called firstname, i will use create view to create the firstname and edit view to edit the firstname, while editing that firstname textbox consist of the value which i provided while creating, likewise while editing combo box it will have the value which i select, but the combo box developed using g:countrySelect doesn't shows the value which i selected during creation

Comment: i want this value on the server side,please ask me if you not still understand, because it very important issue for me i want to solve this immediately, thanks in advance

Comment: @John: please post your code related to gCountrySelect

Comment: this is my code<g:countrySelect name="country" value="${customerInstance?.country}"
                 noSelection="['':'-Choose your country-']"/>

Comment: @John: not actually related, but if you don't mention my name with @ in the comment, I won't receive notification when you post reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the countrySelect tag or create your own.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.CountryTagLib

class FormsTagLib {

static namespace = "bootstrap"

Closure countrySelect = { attrs ->
    if (!attrs.from) {
        attrs.from = CountryTagLib.COUNTRY_CODES_BY_NAME_ORDER
    }

    if (!attrs['valueMessagePrefix']) attrs.optionValue = { CountryTagLib.ISO3166_3[it] }
    attrs.optionKey = { CountryTagLib.ISO3166_3[it] }

    if (!attrs.value) {
        attrs.value = attrs.remove('default')
    }
    out << select(attrs)
}
}
```

and call it as

```
<bootstrap:countrySelect name="country" value="${customerInstance?.country}" noSelection="['':'-Choose your country-']"/>
```

Try this..,.

Comment: thanks a lot its working could you please explain this taglib code

Comment: But this will works for g:countrySelect, i want this to be work for g:timezoneSelect also, please tell me is there any api for solving this problem

Comment: But this will works for g:countrySelect, i want this to be work for g:timezoneSelect also, please tell me is there any api for solving this problem

Comment: This is an exact copy of countrySelect code implementation, I just add a line attrs.optionKey = { CountryTagLib.ISO3166_3[it] } in the implementation. 

By default in the value attribute in the select, original taglib put the country code. So I just add an option value in the taglib and set fullname in it.

Comment: For timezoneSelect just open its implementation and make a copy and create your own and change it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can override optionKey of  tag.

e.g

```
g:countrySelect name="country" noSelection="['':'-Choose your country-']" value="${customerInstance?.country}" optionKey="${{CountryTagLib.ISO3166_3[it]}}"
```

**Now the optionKey and optionValue will be the full country name.**